# OKTA On-Prem Provisioning with SCIM Servers

Tags: scim, okta

I have the free developer edition. I want to provision users to my web site using SCIM. The docs say look under "dashboard/agents". I have no agents tab under dashboards.

https://support.okta.com/articles/Knowledge_Article/46749316-On-Premises-Provisioning-Deployment-Guide?id=kA0F0000000AY3C&q=scim&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1#code

Also for behind a firewall the document says download the "On-Prem Provisioning Agent". I have not been able to find that under "setting/downloads" or anywhere else. Where do I find that?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to contact [Okta Support](https://www.okta.com/support/) or your Okta Sales contact to enable the On-Premises Provisioning feature.